# Отказ выполнения импорта Python-кода в приложении в IOS

Tags: python, ios, swift, xcode, права-доступа

Возникает вот эта ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это происходит, когда запускает вот такой код (картинка 2). Возникает эта ошибка из-за import math. На Mac OS было приблизительно тоже самое. Возникало окошка, что неудалось проверить программу на вредоносность. Однако на Mac OS в настройках можно подтвердить, что можно доверять. Как можно сделать тоже самое для IOS (отключить проверку на вредоносность или подтвердить, что можно доверять)?